# Elixir - update a map which has string keys

Tags: elixir

How do I update a map which has string keys? I want to update the "brand" value.

My code (product is a map with "brand" key):

```
  brand = URI.decode(product["brand"])
  IO.inspect(brand, label: "uri decode")
  brand = elem(Poison.decode(brand), 1)
  IO.inspect(brand, label: "json decode")
  Map.put(product, "brand", brand)
  IO.inspect(product["brand"], label: "actual product brand")
```

outputs:

```
uri decode: "\"e&ggsssssaaqss\""
json decode: "e&ggsssssaaqss"
actual product brand: "%22e%26ggsssssaaqss%22"
```

It isn't updating `product["brand"]`

The `actual product brand` log should equal the `json decode` log if it gets updated.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the original value of `product`?

Comment: You need to assign it back: `product = Map.put(product, "brand", brand)`.

Comment: @Dogbert Thanks

Comment: @Dogbert I will delete this question. Could you please point me in the direction for URI decoding and subsequently JSON decoding the whole map instead of doing it for every field individually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a map has string keys like so:

```
my_map = %{"a" => 1, "b" => 2}
```

You can create a new map with the changed key like this:

```
my_new_map = Map.put(my_map, "a", 100)
```

Or you can rebind the existing `my_map` variable with the updated map like so:

```
my_map = Map.put(my_map, "a", 100)
```

Answer (score 2):

A more terse syntax is the | operator

```
my_map = %{"a" => 1, "b" => 2}
%{my_map | "a" => 100}
```

or also you can use the `put_in` method

```
my_map = %{"a" => 1, "b" => 2}
put_in(my_map["a"], 100)
```